# Delete Many to Many relationship using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-4.1

I've three tables Student (studID, fullName, gender...), Enroll (studID, courseID, date) and Course (courseID,courseName, ...). I used the code below to delete all records from Enroll table with studID 001 where there are about three courses the student signed for. However, it only deletes one record.

```
using(var context = new DBEntities())
{    
var _stud = (from s in context.Students where s.studID == "001" select s).FirstOrDefault();
                var _course = _stud.Courses.FirstOrDefault();
                _course.Students.Remove(_stud);
context.SaveChanges();
}
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: `_course.Students.Load(); _course.Students.ToList().ForEach(s => context.Student.DeleteObject(s));` this should work.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you guys for assisting. Here is how I solved it:

```
using (var context = new DBEntities())
{
    var student = (from s in context.Students where s.studID == "001" select s).FirstOrDefault<Student>();               
    foreach (Course c in student.Courses.ToList())
    {
        student.Courses.Remove(c);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this code :

```
var student = context.Students.Where(p => p.studID == "001").ToList();
foreach (var item in student)
{
    if (student != null)
    {
        var course = student.Courses.ToList();
        if (course != null)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in course)
            {         
                course.Students.Remove(item2);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }           
   }
}
```

Comment: .Include(p => p.studID) produces error unless replaced by "Course." Even so, it only deletes one record (the top from the list)

Answer (score 0):

> I used the code below to delete all records from Enroll table

Are you deleting enrolls or students?

```
Student student = context.Student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.studID == "001");
if (student!=null)
{
    student.Enrolls.Load();
    student.Enrolls.ToList().ForEach(e => context.Enroll.DeleteObject(e));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others looking to this answer you could also do it using include.

```
using(var context = new DBEntities())
{    
    // Get student by id
    var student = context.Students.Include(s => s.Courses).Where(s => s.studID == "001").FirstOrDefault();

    if(student.Courses != null)
    {
        // Retrieve list of courses for that student
        var coursesToRemove = stud.Courses.ToList();

        // Remove courses
        foreach (var course in coursesToRemove)
        {
            student.Courses.Remove(course);
        }

        // Save changes
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```